# Query consult doctrine composite key

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

Hello I am try to take data with dictrine 2.5 from a table but I do not know how to do it.

> SQL FILE

```
DROP DATABASE composite_key;
CREATE DATABASE composite_key;

USE composite_key;

CREATE TABLE company (
    id_company INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(200) null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE reference (
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    id_user INT NOT NULL,
    createat TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_company) REFERENCES company(id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
); 

INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test2');
INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test3');

INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company1');
INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company2');
INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company3');

INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (3,3);
```

> QUERY WHICH I HAVE TRIED

```
$dql = "SELECT r FROM CompositeBundle:Reference r JOIN CompositeBundle:Company c JOIN CompositeBundle:Users u WHERE c.idCompany = 1 AND u.idUser = 1 ";

$dql = "SELECT r FROM CompositeBundle:Reference r JOIN r.idUser JOIN r.idCompany WHERE r.idCompany = 1 AND r.idUser = 1 ";
```

If somone know to do these dql please sat It.

Comment: so what are the errors or non-expected results that you're getting by querying your dqls?

Comment: I do not know how to create the query. For get that data

Comment: again: what is your issue?

Comment: How I to create de query for get that data? I to not Know how to create the query

Comment: are you using Doctrine ORM or Doctrine DBAL? can you share your doctrine entity definition?